# What audio files can you use with SWFOBJECT?

Tags: flash, audio, swfobject, aac

I'm converting some old RealMedia audio-only files to use with the SWFOBJECT Flash player on the web. What's the best container/format to use for the files? I think AAC is probably the best format, but then can you play a *.aac file in the Flash player?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of the Flash Player you run, but version 9 and later supports ADPCM, MP3 and AAC.

More details on [Adobe’s website](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html).

Answer (score 2):

SWFObject is not a media player, it is simply a method for embedding SWF files into your HTML document.  You'll need to use a Flash SWF file that's capable of playing your media files, then embed that SWF into your HTML document using SWFObject.

[SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) is a great (and free) method for playing MP3 and AAC files via HTML5 with a Flash-based fallback.